# A function containing a truth check applied to an array returns an error

Tags: python, function, numpy

If I define the following function:

```
def f(x):
    if x<1.:
        return 0.
    else:
        return x
```

and I try to apply it to an array (in order to have another array as output)

```
import numpy as np
X=np.linspace(0.,2.,100)
print f(X)
```

it returns the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with
 more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Of course I could solve the problem by applying the function to each component of the array separately, but it doesn't seem to be the most efficient way.
What is the right way to define the function?

Comment: You could try to use `map` over all the elements

Comment: Why is applying the function to each component of the array separately not the most efficient way? You need to access each element in order to apply the function on them

Comment: Look at `X<1`.  Could you use that 'mask' as a way of setting many values to 0 at once?  To avoid loops in `numpy` you have to step outside of the box a bit; instead of focusing on changing one element at a time, think about how you can select and change a whole set of elements at once.

Comment: Just in case it wasn't clear from the duplicates, use `np.where`

Comment: There are 2 problems with `f(X)`.  A python `if` is a simple True/False test; it does not iterate in any way.  `X<1` produces a boolean array, many True/False values.  The error says it can't use a such an array in the scalar `if` context.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply that function on each item of the list

```
print(list(map(f, X)))
```

You can also define the function as a lambda function inside the map itself

```
print(list(map(lambda x: 0. if x<1. else x, X)))
```

Or just use numpy masking to select the indexes where `x<1.` and set them to `0.`

```
X[X<1.] = 0.
```

Comment: That **is** applying the function to each component of the array!

Comment: And you just killed vectorization

Comment: That's more like it!  Now I don't have to search for a better duplicate link.